# Multiple verbs in a sentence ending with ている

Tags: grammar, て-form, tense

If I want to state that a thing or multiple things have come to be in more than one state, do I have to use ている more than once. For example:

> お腹は太って大きくなっている
>
> その地域の空間が歪んで、魔界に繋がっている

Are those lines correct? Or would 太って need to be written as 太っていて and 歪んで as 歪んでいて? I would think it's fine to omit ていて but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't need to repeat ている twice.

> その地域の空間が歪んで、魔界に繋がっている

This looks perfect to me. You don't have to say 歪んでいて.

> お腹は太って大きくなっている

This sounds a bit weird. To me お腹が太る and お腹が大きくなる seem almost the same, so I don't get the point of saying both 太る and 大きくなる in this sentence.

And what is the intended meaning of this sentence? Someone's is getting fatter and fatter (progressive)? Or someone's abdomen has become large (present perfective)? If you mean the latter, this sentence would make sense. If you mean the former, note that 太っている almost never means "is getting fatter" (progressive). If you need to say "He is (currently) getting fatter and fatter" using 太る, you have to say 彼はどんどん太って**いって**いる or 彼はどんどん太って**きて**いる.